# Time to recruit UX research participants

Tags: usability, user-behavior

I'm conducting user interviews and wondering how long it takes to recruit research participants?  I need to recruit 20 participants with the only distinguishing requirement being that they have used an industry-specific (can't reveal) site that is popular.  I'm being asked how long it will take for recruitment and then conducting the interviews.

Answer (score 1):

It’s going to depend on how large your recruiting budget, potential participant pool, and incentives are. You can use tools like respondent.io to screen millions of people extremely quickly, but there will be a cost.

I’d suggest creating a screener survey that buries the target site in a list of other sites. Example:

Which sites have you visited in the last 5 years?

- Google
- Amazon
- Home Depot
- Target
- Lowe’s

Potential participants won’t know whether you’re looking to disqualify those who have been to one of the sites, or have not. It’s important to root out “professional participants” who will say anything for money.

You can start by using your company’s email and social channels to distribute the screener survey. If it’s taking too long to find participants, then you can escalate to services like Respondent.

Answer (score 0):

We allow 1 week for B2C participants and 3 weeks for B2B. However, whether you can actually find the specific criteria you are looking for depends on the incident rate (how many there are per population) and how you are going about finding them.
We use specialist third party recruiters for B2B (i.e. like SIS International (not an endorsement, an example) and they have pretty large databases.